# Apache 2.18 denied Rails app (with Apache & Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu-14.04, passenger, phusion

I have a server (ubuntu) which runs some Rails app with Apache & Phusion Passenger.
Every Rails app stopped to work since I upgraded Apache to 2.18.
The server always respond with a 403 status (forbidden) but the public/ directory is not private (I can access via http any .html, .jpg, etc... inside it).
In error.log from Apache there are some entries like:

```
No matching DirectoryIndex (none) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Anyone has any idea?

UPDATE:

I managed to solve this issue reinstalling (purge than install) Apache 2.4 and Passenger (and all its dependencies). Running ok with Apache 2.4.18 and Passenger 5.